# Cakephp 3.7 and PHP 7.2 resulting in error 500

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, php-7.2

I try to upgrade from CakePHP3.6 to 3.7 and from PHP5.6 to 7.2.
The site works with the old settings, upgrading the Cakephp to 3.7 on PHP5.6 is no problem, but when I activate PHP7.2 the cakephp app on my server responds with error 500. Files outside the app are accessible. (for instance a phpinfo() page).

- The output of `sudo tail -100 /var/log/apache2/error.log`

> [authz_core:error] [pid 30539] [client ::1:48076] AH01630: client
>   denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/

- The settings of the apache vhost file

`nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/dev.idphotoagency.com.vhost`

> ```
>    <Directory />
>     Options FollowSymLinks
>     AllowOverride All
> </Directory>
> <Directory /var/www>
>     Options FollowSymLinks
>     AllowOverride All
>     Allow from all
> </Directory>
> ```

- .htaccess page of cakephp app as [here](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess)

What am I missing here?

**edit

Here is the output from `dpkg -l |grep apache2`

```
ii  apache2                               2.4.10-10+deb8u13                                                 amd64        Apache HTTP Server
ii  apache2-bin                           2.4.10-10+deb8u13                                                 amd64        Apache HTTP Server (modules and other binary files)
ii  apache2-data                          2.4.10-10+deb8u13                                                 all          Apache HTTP Server (common files)
ii  apache2-dev                           2.4.10-10+deb8u13                                                 amd64        Apache HTTP Server (development headers)
ii  apache2-doc                           2.4.10-10+deb8u13                                                 all          Apache HTTP Server (on-site documentation)
ii  apache2-mpm-prefork                   2.4.10-10+deb8u13                                                 amd64        transitional prefork MPM package for apache2
ii  apache2-suexec                        2.4.10-10+deb8u13                                                 amd64        transitional package for apache2-suexec-pristine
ii  apache2-suexec-pristine               2.4.10-10+deb8u13                                                 amd64        Apache HTTP Server standard suexec program for mod_suexec
ii  apache2-utils                         2.4.10-10+deb8u13                                                 amd64        Apache HTTP Server (utility programs for web servers)
ii  apache2.2-bin                         2.4.10-10+deb8u13                                                 amd64        Transitional package for apache2-bin
ii  apache2.2-common                      2.4.10-10+deb8u13                                                 amd64        Transitional package for apache2
ii  libapache2-mod-evasive                1.10.1-3                                                          amd64        evasive module to minimize HTTP DoS or brute force attacks
ii  libapache2-mod-fastcgi                2.4.7~0910052141-1.1+deb8u1                                       amd64        Apache 2 FastCGI module for long-running CGI scripts
ii  libapache2-mod-fcgid                  1:2.3.9-1+b1                                                      amd64        FastCGI interface module for Apache 2
ii  libapache2-mod-php5                   5.6.39+dfsg-0+deb8u1                                              amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ii  libapache2-mod-php7.0                 7.0.33-1~dotdeb+8.1                                               amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
rc  libapache2-mod-python                 3.3.1-11                                                          amd64        Python-embedding module for Apache 2
rc  libapache2-mod-ruby                   1.2.6-2                                                           amd64        Embedding Ruby in the Apache2 web server
rc  libapache2-mod-suphp                  0.7.1-3                                                           amd64        Apache2 module to run PHP scripts with the owner permissions
```

I updated the vhost file

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

---

solution

---

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Some ideas: Maybe the required apache modules are not loaded with the new php version? Have you tried with debug=true (last time I got a 500 error in production it was a syntax error)?

Comment: This is an apache configs issues, setting debug mode or making PHP changes won't help. Did the update to 7.2 also happen to update Apache? What version are your running? If you're up to 2.4.6 now you're missing the `Require all granted` listed in the link you provided, it should have replaced  `Allow from all` if so.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: There is still a "Allow from all" to replace in your vhost file. To find more info on the 2.4 migration ahoffner is talking about: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/upgrading.html

Comment: yep, there it comes online. Thanks!!